# Force interface implementations to be Spring Components

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Say I declare an interface MyInterface that only makes sense when its implementation is a Spring component:

```
public interface MyInterface {
}

@Component
public class MyImpl1 implements MyInterface {
}

@Component
public class MyImpl2 implements MyInterface {
}
```

Is there another way to do this without annotating annotating every single implementation class with `@Component`? I would like for the implementations to be registered automatically if they implement MyInterface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-registering all implementations of a specific interface can be done as follows. Note: a full scan of the classpath, including classes that have not been loaded, can be time-consuming with a large classpath.

Create a `@Configuration` class that implements `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` & `PriorityOrdered` as follows. THis will scan and create beans with names as per the package & classname of the implementing class.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.reflections.Reflections;
import org.reflections.scanners.Scanners;
import org.reflections.util.ClasspathHelper;
import org.reflections.util.ConfigurationBuilder;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RootBeanDefinition;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.PriorityOrdered;

import com.example.demo.service.MyInterface;


@Configuration
public class BeanFactoryPostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor, PriorityOrdered {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BeanFactoryPostProcessor.class);

    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {

        Collection<URL> allPackagePrefixes = Arrays.stream(Package.getPackages()).map(p -> p.getName())
                .map(s -> s.split("\\.")[0]).distinct().map(s -> ClasspathHelper.forPackage(s)).reduce((c1, c2) -> {
                    Collection<URL> c3 = new HashSet<>();
                    c3.addAll(c1);
                    c3.addAll(c2);
                    return c3;
                }).get();
        ConfigurationBuilder config = new ConfigurationBuilder().addUrls(allPackagePrefixes)
                .addScanners(Scanners.SubTypes);
        Reflections reflections = new Reflections(config);
        Set<Class<? extends MyInterface>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(MyInterface.class);
        
        classes.stream().forEach(clazz -> {
            String className = clazz.getName();
            BeanDefinition beanDefn= new RootBeanDefinition(className);
            registry.registerBeanDefinition(className, beanDefn);
            logger.debug("Registering bean {}", className);
        });
        
    }

    public int getOrder() {
        return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }

    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        // do nothing
        
    }
}
```

Autowire the created beans in by using the package & classname of the implementing class as a Qualifier as follows:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("com.example.demo.rest.MyImpl2")
MyInterface myInterface;
```

There is a dependency on org.reflections:reflections as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
    <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You should write Bean Post Processor for your interface `MyInterface`, that before start spring app will look throw over all classes and find all that implements that interface, then register all classes to ApplicationContext